# How to localize Flex/Actionscript "enums" to ensure bindability?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3, localization, resourcemanager

I have a simulated enum as follows:

```
public class Sport {
    public static const BASEBALL:Sport = new MyEnum("Baseball", "Baseball ...");
    public static const FOOTBALL:Sport = new MyEnum("Football", "Football ...");

    public var label:String;
    public var description:String;

    public function Sport(label:String, description:String):void {
        this.label = label;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

And buttons that bind to these enums as follows:

```
<mx:Button label="{Sport.BASEBALL.label}" toolTip="{Sport.BASEBALL.description}"/>
```

I now need to localize this enum, but haven't had much luck getting the binding to update along with everything else when I update the locale:

```
resourceManager.localeChain = [ localeComboBox.selectedItem ];
```

I've tried binding getters to the "change" event that supposedly gets thrown by ResourceManager, but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
<mx:Button label="{resourceManager.getString('resourceBundleName', Sport.BASEBALL.label)}" toolTip="{resourceManager.getString('resourceBundleName', Sport.BASEBALL.description)}"/>
```

where `Sport.BASEBALL.label` and `Sport.BASEBALL.description` are the keys from your ResourceBundle.

You can also take a look at [BabelFx](http://babelfx.org/) which eliminates the need to insert all those ugly `{resourceManager.getString(...)}` statements. It uses runtime injection to localize your application.

Comment: True, this is an option. It doesn't feel optimal, though. I'll have a look at BabelFX.